# R- Optimx for exponential function with 2 parameters - cannot evaluate function at initial parameter values

Tags: r, mathematical-optimization

I feel like I missed something very obvious but after an hour of fiddling/googling I cannot get this to work. Code:

```
#Generate data from exponential model

xdata<-seq_len(100)
ydata<-2*exp(-2*(xdata+rnorm(100)))

#Fit exponential model to data
firstorder<-function(C0,k){
 ynew<-C0*exp(-k*xdata)
 RMSE<-sum((ynew-ydata)^2,na.rm=TRUE)
 return(RMSE)
}

#Initial parameter values
params<-c(1,1)

#Optimize
optimx(params,firstorder)
```

Error in optimx.check(par, optcfg$ufn, optcfg$ugr, optcfg$uhess, lower,  : 
 Cannot evaluate function at initial parameters

I tried a variety of ways to input the parameters.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try

```
optimx(params, function(x) firstorder(x[1], x[2]))
```

Comment: It works! Thanks a lot. So the trick is to give a single argument to optimx?

Comment: What if I wanted to expand the function with 2 parameters specifying the x and y data to be used? So `firstorder(C0,k,xdata,ydata){`. Can I still use optimx to optimize with respect to the C0 and k parameters with fixed `xdata,ydata` ?

Comment: You need to read `?optimx` carefully and in particular note the `...` argument.

Comment: So the function changes to `firstorder(C0,k,xdata,ydata)`. After reading the `?optimx` documentation I tried the following code: `optimx(params,function(x) firstorder(x[1] x[2]),xdata=xdata1,ydata=ydata1)`. Problem is, I get the evaluate at initial parameter values error again.

Comment: If C0 and k are to be varied they must be in a single object.  The fixed parameters are passed separately.  `f <- function(x, xdata, ydata) ...; optimx(start, f, xdata = xdata, ydata = ydata)`.  See `genrose.f` in the examples section of `?optimx` for another example.

Comment: Thanks! Putting both the parameters and the data in 1 matrix did the trick.