# Passing Fixed and Variable parameters to Optimx

Tags: r, mathematical-optimization

This is a syntax question and probably has a simple solution but I can't find it covered anywhere on SO for the optimx package.

### Minimal working example & Question

I have a function like:

```
ToOptimise = function(a,b,d,e){
(a-1)^2 + (b-2)^2 + (d-3)^2 +(e-4)^2
}
```

I can optimise select parameters in mle2 quite easily:

```
library(bbmle)

Calib2 = mle2(ToOptimise,
              start = list(a = 1, d = 10),
              fixed = list(b = 2, e = 2))
```

This is not really the right tool though as it is not a maximum likelihood problem.

**I want to find a way to pass fixed and optimisable parameters to Optimx as easily**

I plan to do several calibrations holding different parameters fixed at any time and so do not want to have to redo the function hardcoding in some parameters.

### My attempt that don't work

```
library(optimx)

ToOptimiseVector = function(Theta){
  a = Theta[1]
  b = Theta[2]
  d = Theta[3]
  e = Theta[4]
  (a-1)^2 + (b-2)^2 + (d-3)^2 +(e-4)^2
}


Calib1  = optimx( par = c(1,2,1,2),
                  fn = ToOptimiseVector,
                  Theta[2] = 2, Theta[4] = 2)
```

### Another related Question on Stack Overflow

Another optimx syntax question that does not look at fixed and optimisable parameters is:

- [R- Optimx for exponential function with 2 parameters - cannot evaluate function at initial parameter values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22176082/r-optimx-for-exponential-function-with-2-parameters-cannot-evaluate-function/22176269#22176269)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Added a `opt` parameter to the `fn`. Just pass this `opt` vector into `optimx()`. Any non NA values will become fixed.

```
ToOptimiseVector <- function(Theta, opt = rep(NA, 4)){

# Check if any of opt is not NA
if (any(!sapply(opt, is.na))) {
     i = !sapply(opt, is.na)
# Fix non-NA values
     Theta[i] <- opt[i]
     }

a <- Theta[1]
b <- Theta[2]
d <- Theta[3]
e <- Theta[4]
return((a-1)^2 + (b-2)^2 + (d-3)^2 +(e-4)^2)
}
```

Seems to work.

```
Calib1  = optimx( par = c(1,2,1,2), fn = ToOptimiseVector, opt = c(NA, 2, NA, 2))

Calib2  = optimx( par = c(1,2,1,2), fn = ToOptimiseVector)

> Calib1
               p1       p2      p3       p4 value fevals gevals niter convcode kkt1  kkt2 xtimes
Nelder-Mead 0.9998974 5.517528 3.00022 10.83214     4    103     NA    NA        0 TRUE FALSE   0.02
BFGS        1.0000000 4.000000 3.00000  8.00000     4      6      3    NA        0 TRUE FALSE   0.00
> Calib2
              p1       p2     p3       p4        value fevals gevals niter convcode  kkt1 kkt2 xtimes
Nelder-Mead 1.000936 1.999793 3.0006 4.000256 1.344336e-06    227     NA    NA        0 FALSE TRUE   0.01
BFGS        1.000000 2.000000 3.0000 4.000000 3.566556e-23     16      3    NA        0  TRUE TRUE   0.00
```

Comment: Hi @Vlo. You are right about the error for e. I have changed that in the question. Can you give me the code you use for calling the optim function?

Comment: The sapply in `if (any(!sapply(opt, is.na)))` is unneeded, `if (any(!is.na(opt)))` works also

Answer (score 1):

The trick is that the starting params and the arguments to the function to be optimized have to be aligned. Please see if the following helps you at all.

```
library(optimx)

ToOptimiseVector <- function(Theta){
  a <- Theta[1]
  b <- Theta[2]
  d <- Theta[3]
  e <- Theta[4]
  (a-1)^2 + (b-2)^2 + (d-3)^2 +(e-4)^2
}


start <- c(1,0,1,1)
start <- c(1,0,0,0)
start <- c(1,2,1,2)

Calib1  <- optimx( par=start,
                  fn = ToOptimiseVector)
```

This gives warning messages, but you do get a result.

```
 > Calib1
            p1 p2 p3 p4 value fevals gevals niter convcode kkt1 kkt2
Nelder-Mead  1  2  3  4     0      4      4    NA        0 TRUE TRUE
BFGS         1  2  3  4     0      4      4    NA        0 TRUE TRUE
            xtimes
Nelder-Mead      0
BFGS             0
```

Hope you can start with this and proceed.

Comment: Hi @Ram. One of the things I want is to be able to fix some parameters at some chosen levels.  For example in the mle2 example above I could fix minimise the function given that b = e = 2. You are right with the not defining e however, I have fixed this above.